# {plotrix} - gap.plot - line not connecting to upper panel of graph with y-axis break

Tags: r, plotrix

I have a dataset that includes one point that is much higher in magnitude than the others; I am trying to use `gap.plot` to show this point on the graph without introducing unnecessary white-space. However, my line plot skips over the point in the top panel of the graph, leaving it isolated.

Code is as follows:

```
year<-c(2001:2015)
y<-c(30, 13, 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 309, 7, 1, 58, 1, 62, 69, 49)
par(bty="n") #Deletes box
gap.plot(
  year,y
  , type="b" 
  , ylim=c(0,325)
  , gap=c(100,275)
  , gap.axis="y"
  , xaxt = "n"
  , xtics =NA
  , xticlab=NA
  , xlim =c(2001,2015)
  , xlab="Year"
  , ylab="Positive Samples"
  , pch=15

)
axis(1,at=c(2001:2015))
abline(h=seq(100,103), col="white",lwd=5) #Eliminates horizontal lines
axis.break(axis=2,breakpos=100,style="slash")
```

I end up with the following graph:
[image: gap.plot example graph]
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could also use `plot` in which you specify `type="l" ` add  `points()` and then add break with `axis.break`.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I tried plotting normally using `plot` with `type="l"` as you suggested, but the axes were the normal length. 

To my understanding, `axis.break` only adds the symbol to an already-broken axis.